# Setting a property in Pagination component from a urql query data store causes page to hang

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a problem linking a result I fetch with urql to a Pagination component. It is probably something simple but I am at lost if this is a mistake of me, or something wrong in the Pagination component I am using.

I use Pagination from IBM Carbon svelte Component library (https://carbon-svelte.vercel.app/components/Pagination) and fetch the data with urql.

This is the urql part of the component:

```
   initClient({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/query',
    });

    const jobs = operationStore(`
    query($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!){
       findJobs(
       filter:
       {
       duration: {gt:120}
       },
       orderBy:
       {
       field: "num_nodes",
       order: ASC
       }
       page:
       {
          limit: $limit,
          offset: $offset
       }) {
       items {
          id
          jobId
          userId
          startTime
          duration
        }
       count
     }
     }
`,{limit, offset});

query(jobs);
```

That is the template code:

```
{#if $jobs.fetching}
    <Loading />
{:else if $jobs.error}
  Error: {$jobs.error.message}
{:else }
    <Select labelText="Sort column" bind:selected={count}>
        <SelectItem value=100 text="100" />
        <SelectItem value=200 text="200" />
        <SelectItem value=300 text="300" />
    </Select>

    <pre> {jobs.data.findJobs.count} </pre>

       <DataTable
         headers={[{ key: 'jobId', value: 'JobId' }, { key: 'userId', value: 'UserId' }, { key: 'startTime', value: 'Start time' }, { key: 'duration', value: 'Duration' }]}
        rows={$jobs.data.findJobs.items}
     />
     <Pagination totalItems={count} pageSizes={[10, 25, 50]} page={page} pageSize={limit} on:update={handlePaging} />
{/if}
```

With the Select component I can update count and it is rerendered in the Pagination component. As you can see I also output the result of the urql query `{jobs.data.findJobs.count}`, and it has the correct value.

Now if I link by any means the urql store to the Pagination property, the page hangs and does not rerender:

```
{#if $jobs.fetching}
    <Loading />
{:else if $jobs.error}
  Error: {$jobs.error.message}
{:else }
       <DataTable
         headers={[{ key: 'jobId', value: 'JobId' }, { key: 'userId', value: 'UserId' }, { key: 'startTime', value: 'Start time' }, { key: 'duration', value: 'Duration' }]}
        rows={$jobs.data.findJobs.items}
     />
     <Pagination totalItems={$jobs.data.findJobs.count} pageSizes={[10, 25, 50]} page={page} pageSize={limit} on:update={handlePaging} />
{/if}
```

I have no clue why it breaks as soon as I use the store as a property.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `<pre> {jobs.data.findJobs.count} </pre>`?

Comment: It is the total count of the query items, and it it outputs a number (867548 in this particular case ;-). BTW subscribing to the store (```$jobs.data.findJobs.count```) when access count also does not change anything. I suspected it has to do something linking a store to a property, but as far as I know this should work.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are setting `limit` and `offset` to reasonable values and it's not just taking forever to return the results?

Comment: Sure limit and offset are fine, in the first version without using count I can just step through the pages. I now replaced urql with Apollo client and svelte-apollo. Same issue: As soon as I link  ```totalItems={$jobs.data.findJobs.count} to the count result the render hangs. And it really hangs, I need to reopen the tab.

Answer (score 1):

After some more debugging I found the problem. The Pagination Component could not handle the very large total items count. If I use a query with a reasonably small item count everything works as expected.

Maybe I extend the Pagination component so that it also does something reasonable (output more than 1000 item for example) and not just hangs forever.

Sorry to bother you!